# Unable to import any database to Xampp PHPmyAdmin regaurdlesss of size

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Recently every file I import into PHPmyAdmin [4.7.0] comes back with the error:

> You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to  documentation for a workaround for this limit.

Actual file size does not seem to matter, the file I'm trying right now is only 33kb SQL file, but I still get the message.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version? What type of file are you importing?

Comment: Adding a .SQL file into verison 4.7.0